# the wife/the husband/the children - your wife/your husband/your children

Tags: definite-article

There is this entry in a dictionary:

3. often facetious or derogatory my; our: **the wife goes out on Thursdays**

Instead of "my wife", "the wife" is used. Is it really facetious or derogatory?

**How is the husband?**

**How are the children?**

What difference would there be if "your" was used instead of "the"?

Comment: The implication of using **the** instead of **my/your** would depend entirely on the context. In casual conversation, generally among men, it's not unusual or necessarily derogatory. One man might ask another: **How's the wife?**  as a polite inquiry. On the other hand, some people would dislike the expression, and **How's the husband** is rare.

Comment: OK. But what's the point in using it at all?

Comment: Some interesting discussion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/the-wife-instead-of-my-wife-are-there-any-other-contexts-where-a-possessive?rq=1)